# How to plot function results with matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have made a function which returns a value for a force depending on the z position (z_pos). I would like to plot these results (shear diagram for the engineers here), however I get the following error:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I have tried it both with arange and linspace, see the code here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#values in kN and m
FyFL = 520
FyRL = 1246
L = 40.
Lf1 = 2.
Lf2 = 25.5
g = 9.81
W = 60000
q = (3*g*W/L)/1000 #kN/m
print q 

def int_force_y(FyFL, FyRL, L, Lf1, Lf2, q, z_pos):

    if z_pos <= Lf1:
        int_fc_y = -q*z_pos
    elif z_pos > Lf1 and z_pos < Lf1+Lf2:
        int_fc_y = -q*Lf1 + FyFL-q*z_pos
    elif z_pos >= Lf2 and z_pos <= 40.:
        int_fc_y = -q*Lf1 + FyFL-q*(Lf1+Lf2)-q*z_pos
    else:
        return "No valid z_pos"

    return int_fc_y

z_pos = np.arange(0,41,1)
y = int_force_y(FyFL, FyRL, L, Lf1, Lf2, q, z_pos)
plt.plot(z_pos,y)
plt.show()
```

Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting has nothing to do with the plotting but arises when you call `int_force_y`. The argument `z_pos` is a `np.ndarray`. If you now compare this to eg. `Lf1` in your function then this gives you a boolean array where each element indicates if the corresponding element of `z_pos` is smaller  or equal to `Lf1` in case of your first `if` statement. As some elements are smaller or equal and some are not, he cannot decide whether he should consider this as `True` or `False` and asks you to use [`.any()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) to indicate that it should be `True` if any element is `True` or [`.all()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) to indicate that it should be `True` if all elements are `True`.

But both or these cases do not do what you want them to do. You want a decision for each element individually and to then set the corresponding value in `int_fc_y` accordingly. You can do this by a for-loop or more elegantly by using [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) and [`np.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html). Just use this function to produce your result array instead of your version:

```
def int_force_y(FyFL, FyRL, L, Lf1, Lf2, q, z_pos):
    if (z_pos>40.).any():
        return "No valid z_pos"
    int_force_y = np.zeros_like(z_pos)
    int_fc_y[z_pos<=Lf1] = -q*z_pos
    int_fc_y[np.logical_and(z_pos > Lf1,
                            z_pos < Lf1+Lf2)] = -q*Lf1 + FyFL-q*z_pos
    int_fc_y[np.logical_and(z_pos >= Lf2,
                            z_pos <= 40.)] = -q*Lf1 + FyFL-q*(Lf1+Lf2)-q*z_pos
    return int_fc_y
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens because you are asking python whether if an array is larger or smaller than certain value:

```
if z_pos <= Lf1:
```

This might be truth for some values and false for some others, with leaves the question of whether if that statement is true or false ambiguous.

You can try :

```
if np.array(z_pos <= Lf1).any():
```

or

```
if np.array(z_pos <= Lf1).all():
```

depending on what you want. 
Same for the following if statements.

Comment: That will not give him the desired result as then the function will only return one value and not an array of all result values.